# The question count in the network profile's account tab is sometimes incorrect

Tags: bug, questions, statistics, network-profile

The question count in the network profile's account tab is sometimes incorrect.

E.g.: https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt?tab=accounts

[image]

vs. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/210/franck-dernoncourt:

[image]